# remove blank pages from word file

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I am using a word object to reference the word document. I am copying some images to each page and converting that 150+ pages word file to PDF.

```
Dim wordapp As Object
Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

To add 1st page to that word file i am using

```
wordapp.documents.Add
```

To add next pages i am using the code in next line,

```
wordapp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Add
```

Above code does not insert any blank page in word file and conversion of same to pdf is succesfull.

For your information,

On my computer environment is Windows 10, Office 2013.  But When i use same on another computer then it introduces blank pages. Here Windows 10 and Office 2010.

complete code is here.
    pagenumber 
specifies that its first time we are trying to create word dcument or not. so nest time only page is added

```
If pagenumber = 1 Then
Dim wordapp As Object

Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wordapp.documents.Add
wordapp.Visible = False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
With wordapp.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
     .LeftMargin = 36
     .RightMargin = 36
     .TopMargin = 36
     .BottomMargin = 36
End With
Else
    'add page at end AND copy the picture ahead of it
    wordapp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Add
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
End If

Dim selrange As Range
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks("" & workbookname).Sheets("Tax Invoice     Format").Range("A1:L47").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
wordapp.Selection.Goto wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, count:=pagenumber
wordapp.Selection.Paste (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
wordapp.ActiveDocument.inlineshapes(pagenumber).LockAspectRatio =     msoFalse
wordapp.ActiveDocument.inlineshapes(pagenumber).Height = 735
wordapp.ActiveDocument.inlineshapes(pagenumber).Width = 540
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

pagenumber = pagenumber + 1
*loop continues*
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question? `wordapp.documents.Add` adds an empty word document with an empty first page. The 
`wordapp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Add` adds a new empty page.

Comment: when I am using same code another machine it inserts 2 pages randomly

Comment: either tell me how to find a blank page from word file and delete it or let me know why multiple pages are being inserted.

Comment: it sounds like wordapp.Selection.Goto wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, count:=pagenumber goes to just before the end of page marker in office2013 and to the end of page marker in 2010. The result is that your paste is inside the page in 2013 (pushing the end of page marker down) but in 2010 it pastes after the end of page and so into a new page. You probably need to move one char back after your goto and before teh paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having difficulties is that `Sections.Add` is not the way to insert new pages into a Word document. A Word "Section" defines a set of page layout formatting, such as portrait vs. landscape, different margin settings, different headers and footers, etc.

There are different kinds of "section breaks", one of which does *not* create a new page. If you don't specify the kind of page break, Word uses the local default setting (can be user-determined). So probably on the one machine "Next Page" is the default and on the other "Continuous".

The correct way to insert a new page is

```
Range.InsertBreak Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak 'or the long equivalent: 7
```

In addition, your code is inefficient and otherwise inaccurate. As in Excel, it's better to work with the underlying objects, especially the `Range` object.

Here are some suggestions:

```
'Declare and assign these as appropriate - unsure since we don't see all the code...
Dim wordDoc as Object
Dim wordRange as Object 
Dim wordInlineShape as Object

If pagenumber = 1 Then
  Dim wordapp As Object

  Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set wordDoc = wordapp.documents.Add
  Set wordRange = wordDoc.Content
  wordapp.Visible = False
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
  With wordDoc.PageSetup
     .LeftMargin = 36
     .RightMargin = 36
     .TopMargin = 36
     .BottomMargin = 36
  End With
Else
    'add page at end AND copy the picture ahead of it
    wordRange.Collapse 0 'Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
    wordRange.InsertBreak 7
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
End If

Dim selrange As Range
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks("" & workbookname).Sheets("Tax Invoice Format").Range("A1:L47").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

wordRange.Collapse 0 'Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
wordRange.Paste (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
Set wordInlineShape = wordDoc.Inlineshapes(pagenumber).LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
wordInlineShape.Height = 735
wordInlineShape.Width = 540
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

pagenumber = pagenumber + 1
*loop continues*
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Executed my project using your code. It introduces 2 pages after every page break. The same I observed previously that's why tried it using sections. Is there any way we can delete an extra added page?

Comment: Hi Cindy Meister,

I changed a line from your code as follows
    wordRange.InsertBreak 3

and my code is working fine now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ShekharNalawade Interesting... I'm disturbed that this works because it is inserting section breaks (continuous kind). Difficult to be sure, but I'm guessing the pictures are so large that each insertion is filling an entire page completely? In that case, you may need only a Chr(13) (`InsertParagraph`) after each picture, rather than a "break". Try `wordRange.InsertAfter Chr(13)` just before `wordRange.Collapse 0` and leave out inserting a Break.

Comment: Tried your code still it introduces a blank page when I use this code on another machine. It works fine on my machine. Both Machine's hardware and word configuration are same.

Comment: I've lost the thread a bit. Can you be more precise as to which code is meant? That posted in my question, or the tweak I mentioned in comments? If the latter, used with the code in my Answer, the code in your Question or something different? Also, I think it would be very useful for you to analyze the result with non-printing characters displayed in Word so that you can SEE what is "pushing".

Comment: I have used this code.
    wordRange.InsertAfter Chr(13) But issue remains same.